# Starting two methods at the same time in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am trying to run two methods at the same time in Python. One of them plays a sound and the other one records it. Both methods work fine but I could not figure it out how to start them at the same time both multiprocessing and threading were tried. Whereas I am almost sure now that it can't be solved with threading.

```
def listen_to_audio()

def play_audio()
```

Any ideas? (They don't have to finish at the same time but they should both start within a second.)

That is the code, sorry for not posting it in the beginning:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import time
from math import *
from getopt import *
import threading

def make_sin(f0=1000.,ampl=30000,rate=22050,length=5.):
  a = 2. * pi * f0/rate              
  n = int(rate * length)
  wav=''
  for i in range(0, n):
    f = int(ampl*sin(a*i))
    wav += chr(f & 0xFF) + chr((f & 0xFF00) >> 8)
  return wav



def play_audio(forHowLong):
    data = make_sin(f0=1000.,ampl=30000,rate=22050,length=5.)

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio() #sets up portaudio system
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(2),
                channels=1,
                rate=22050,
                output=True)

    start = time.time()
    while time.time() < start + forHowLong*0.5:    
            stream.write(data)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


def listen_to_audio(forHowLong):
    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = forHowLong
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* recording")

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    print("* done recording")

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()


def main():

#start play_audio and record_audio here at the same time



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? Please supply some example code, with details of what went wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for `Threading`

Comment: why can't it be solved with threading..?

Comment: I don't know but I've tried all ways of threading including all posted ones here til now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import threading,time
def play1():
    while time.time() <= start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio).start()
def play2():
    while time.time() <= start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target=play_audio).start()
start_time=time.time()+20
threading.Thread(target=play1).start()
threading.Thread(target=play2).start()
```

This should work for you, it starts each function, and in each function it waits until it is the right time :)

Comment: Still a newbie here, but i guess this is the best answer.

Comment: Here is an upvote for that cool name of yours, but since i don't know much about programming and threading and all, i don't want to confuse OP in case your answer isn't right. :)

Comment: hey, I've tried your example, it also did not work. I am starting to think that this has to do with pyaudio..

Comment: `time.time()` returns a floating point number, so the likelihood of either `while` check hitting exactly the desired start time is very small.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Fixed so that `<=` is what is being checked, that way, it does not have to be `==` to the start time, because, as you said, it does indeed have a small likelyhood of hitting the start time. Thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

I would use threads:

```
import threading

threads = []
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=play_audio))

map(lambda x: x.start(), threads)
```

EDIT: not sure if map will start the threads **absolutely** at the same time, but it should be very very close

Comment: It won't be *absolutely* the same time, but WELL within the 1 second tolerance OP references in the question :). -- As a side note, I'd start them in a loop, not `map`.  Using `map` for side-effects is generally not considered good coding style.

Comment: thank you for your code - I've tried it, unfortunately it did not work I am starting to think that this could be because of pyaudio

Comment: could you post the error code you're seeing when the threads fail? I can't imagine why pyaudio would not be thread-safe

Comment: here's the console output for one of the threading codes:2012-11-16 21:38:47.792 Python[2947:f07] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign

Comment: 2nd part:CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Digidesign CoreAudio: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
2012-11-16 21:38:47.794 Python[2947:f07] Cannot find function pointer NewDigiCoreAudioPlugIn for factory B8A063B5-2F3D-444A-88CB-D0B8F1B22042 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x100600d90 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/Digidesign CoreAudio.plugin> (bundle, not loaded

Comment: 3rd part:
)
* recording
* done recording

But I have been ignoring these errors since the methods themselves work just fine.. but now I think I'll have a closer look

Answer (score 2):

You could start with:

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio).start()
threading.Thread(target=play_audio).start()
```

Comment: but then you have the lag of the `threading.Thread` overhead happening between each `.start()`

Comment: @COpython I'll swap you that over head for generating a list using map with a lambda and discarding it? :)

Comment: fair enough, I think we both have good answers, but apparently OP now claims it can't be solved with threads..?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you IT Ninja,

your code did the job but I had to change it a bit to:

```
def main():
start_time=time.time()+1
def play1():
    while time.time() < start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio(5)).start()
def play2():
    while time.time() < start_time:
        pass
    threading.Thread(target=play_audio(5)).start()

threading.Thread(target=play1).start()
threading.Thread(target=play2).start()
```

Now it works:)
Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

Why to start both functions using threads? You can simply call first function and initiate second one using thread within first function.

```
import threading


def play_audio():
    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_audio).start()
    #rest of code for play_audio
```

I think the delay here will be very less.

Comment: Just a different way of doing it. if both functions are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after the fact but,

1. The threads may start  at the same time but playback / recording won't start at the same time due to limitations with windows. There is actually a buffer on both behind the scene causing an (unknown or controllable) delay.
2. The best way to do this is to create an asynchronous read / write stream (one stream that does both read and write). That is, make a stream with a callback function and define both input=True and output=True (I'm assuming pyaudio here).

I'm not sure how pyaudio implements threading behind the scenes, especially if it's blocking audio, but another issue is the GIL (global interpreter lock). I didn't research enough into the current state of things and how in behaves under different python implementations, but IIRC only one thread can run python code at a given time, so python for the most part isn't very multi threading friendly at the moment AFAIK

Answer (score -1):

I'd create a `def startBoth()` to wrap both functions, importing both listen_to_audio and play_audio as necessary. Once you initiate `startBoth()`, it would call both functions.

Comment: What if one of the functions is blocking? The second one won't get called until the first one returns.