# Is playing back an ongoing recording possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, audio

I want to record the audio being captured by the mic of my laptop and then say after some delay, play it back through the headphones connected to laptop. What I tried is recording the incoming audio in batches of 10 sec as background process & after the 1st audio clip of 10 sec is recorded, start playing it back in the background through the headphones. The problem that I am facing is that when in the end of recording, I combine all the batches of sound clips, some sound samples are lost in the process of stopping one recording & restarting the recording of next incoming sound.

So, is it possible to let the recording continue & after some samples are collected start playing that ongoing recording ? Or is there any other work around to this samples being lost?

Comment: Check SO post over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711672/simultaneous-record-audio-from-mic-and-play-it-back-with-effect-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you just want record and playback, `pyaudio` has good basic examples [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

However, if you need to customize delay between record and playback then there are various approaches depending upon complexity and efforts.
One way is to record & save chunks of audio files and play them sequentially after some time delay between recording and playback.

It is possible to save small chunks to objects in memory (although I haven't tried that yet).

The playback and recording can be threaded or spawned to run simultaneously. I attempted multiprocessing, however, since I don't have multi-core CPU it may not be seem to be working. You are welcome to develop it further.

So, as discussed first we record and save chunks of audio files using `record_audio` function.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def record_audio(AUDIO_FILE):
    #Create audio stream    
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    # begin recording
    print"* recording audio clip: ",AUDIO_FILE

    frames = []
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    #print"* done recording audio clip:", AUDIO_FILE

    #cleanup objects
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    #save frames to audio clips
    print"* sending data to audio file:", AUDIO_FILE
    wf = wave.open(AUDIO_FILE , 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
```

Next, we define function to play audio  chunks using `play_audio` function.

```
def play_audio(AUDIO_FILE):
    #open saved audio clip
    wf2 = wave.open(AUDIO_FILE , 'rb')

    #Introduce  playback delay
    time.sleep(AUDIO_DELAY)


    #Define playback audio stream
    stream2 = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf2.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf2.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf2.getframerate(),
                output=True)

    data = wf2.readframes(CHUNK)
    print" *************************** playing back audio file:", AUDIO_FILE
    while data != '':        
        stream2.write(data)
        data = wf2.readframes(CHUNK)

    stream2.stop_stream()
    stream2.close()

    p.terminate()
```

Then we put two functions together in `main` and  (attempt to )  kick off simultaneously.

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 2               #stereo
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 5         #record chunks of 5 sec
    TOTAL_RECORD_NUMBER = 5    # total chunks to record and play
    AUDIO_DELAY = 5.0          #playback delay in seconds

    x = 0

    while x < TOTAL_RECORD_NUMBER:

        #define audio file clip
        AUDIO_FILE = "audio{0}.wav".format(x)

        #initialize pyaudio
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()        

        #Kick off record audio function process
        p1 = Process(target = record_audio(AUDIO_FILE))
        p1.start()

        #kick off play audio function process
        p2 = Process(target = play_audio(AUDIO_FILE))        
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()


        #increment record counter
        x += 1
```

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
* recording audio clip:  audio0.wav
* sending data to audio file: audio0.wav
 *************************** playing back audio file: audio0.wav
* recording audio clip:  audio1.wav
* sending data to audio file: audio1.wav
 *************************** playing back audio file: audio1.wav
* recording audio clip:  audio2.wav
* sending data to audio file: audio2.wav
 *************************** playing back audio file: audio2.wav
* recording audio clip:  audio3.wav
* sending data to audio file: audio3.wav
 *************************** playing back audio file: audio3.wav
* recording audio clip:  audio4.wav
* sending data to audio file: audio4.wav
 *************************** playing back audio file: audio4.wav
>>>
```

As you can see , the processes did not spawn simultaneously. You may develop it further.

Hope this helps.